# Missing assets in binary framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcodebuild, ios-frameworks

I'm fairly new to working with binary frameworks. I'm finding that assets are not being included in the binary framework even after including them in `Copy Bundle Resources`. I've been looking at the documentation here https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/itcaec37c2a6, but not seeing anything about including assets with my build script.

If i skip the binary framework build script and pull directly from the repo using pods there is no issues.

Comment: Use `resource_bundles` if you are using Cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

You should build your Bundle target with `xcodebuild` and then copy it to your xcframework, so you final xcframework structure will look like that:[image: xcframework structure]